# what does this.base means in preact?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, preact

Can **this.base** refers to current component in  Preactjs ? 
I have a code which has a line

```
const rect = this.base.getBoundingClientRect();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.base` is to a reference to the root DOM element of your current Component.

It's the JSX element that is returned by your Component's `render` function.

Thus, you can use `this.base` once your Component has been mounted.

Here's a small example of the lifecycle from the [official documentation](https://preactjs.com/guide/v10/external-dom-mutations#technique):

```
class Example extends Component {
  shouldComponentUpdate() {
    // do not re-render via diff:
    return false;
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    // you can do something with incoming props here if you need
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // now mounted, can freely modify the DOM:
    let thing = document.createElement('maybe-a-custom-element');
    this.base.appendChild(thing);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    // component is about to be removed from the DOM, perform any cleanup.
  }

  render() {
    return <div class="example" />;
  }
}
```